# Null space of a positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Does the null space of a positive semidefinite matrix have a special structure? Specifically, when will it be of a finite (or infinite) cardinality?

Comment: What do you mean by "size"? The dimension is always finite.

Comment: By size I mean cardinality

Comment: What is the underlying field for the matrices?

Comment: Complex matrices

Comment: Any null space is a finite-dimensional (complex) vector space. It is finite if and only if it is $\{0\}$.